# Contextual Outlook add-ins for Outlook appointment

Tags: outlook, calendar, office-js, outlook-web-addins

According to the documentation of conetextual addin i.e. "Contextual add-ins are Outlook add-ins that activate based on text in a message or APPOINTMENT", it is possible to use it with outlook appointment or event.

If it is, what should i use in the below code to make it work for APPOINTMENT

Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message"
    Rule xsi:type="ItemHasKnownEntity" EntityType="PhoneNumber" Highlight="all"

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. Setting `ItemType` to `Appointment` is the correct solution. However, there is an existing issue with that `ItemType`. We have an issue in our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the `Appointment` value for the `ItemType` attribute.

```
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
</Rule>
```

Read more about that in the [ItemIs rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/activation-rules#itemis-rule) section of MSDN.